# SpringBoot 1.4.0, can we explicitly set value for DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I can see the following in SpringBoot's autoconfiguration logs

```
DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp matched
...

DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat matched
...

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcpPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched
...

DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration matched
...
```

I want to use tomcat as my datasource. I looked at [SpringBoot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) and found the following property for DataSourceConfiguration

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

By doing so, I was able to get

```
DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat matched
...
```

and

```
DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp did not match
...
```

But the metadata part still has both tomcat and DBCP

```
DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcpPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched
...
      DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration matched
...
```

Is there a way to set the value for DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration?

Comment: Just remove the commons-dbcp dependency, if that isn't possible ignore this as it will show nothing if there is no actual DBCP datasource available in your context.

Comment: not possible to remove the dependency. any idea if there is an option where we can pick which jars should be included while starting the spring application.

Comment: No there isn't, what is on the classpath is what is included. Why isn't it possible to remove the dependency? Why do you need 2 implementations of a datasource?